# Saltos de línea entre dos divs

Tags: html, css

**Quisiera sustituir los saltos de línea "br" por saltos de línea más legibles en código CSS.**

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<div class="a">
   ...
   ...
   ...
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="b">
   ...
   ...
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: ¿A qué equivale un salto de línea?

Comment: En HTML a la etiqueta <br/>

Comment: ¿No probaste utilizar márgenes?

Comment: Eso estoy pidiendo una posible respuesta en lugar de usar varios brs... ¿qué etiqueta o propiedad debo usar en CSS? ¿margin? ¿padding? ¿em?

Comment: Esa es mi pregunta: ¿a cuántos px/em corresponde el alto de una línea? Sabiendo eso, sabríamos qué cantidad poner entre a y b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En CSS existe el [selector adyacente](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) (`+`) que selecciona el siguiente elemento que cumpla una condición dada. Por ejemplo, para seleccionar el `.b` que va justo después del `.a` (el caso de la pregunta), entonces el selector sería `.a + .b`.

Suponiendo que una línea tenga un alto de 1em, entonces como tienes 4 saltos de línea tendrás que poner 4em de distancia entre `.a` y `.b` (por ejemplo, añadiendo un `margin-top` a `.b`):

```
.a + .b {
    margin-top: 4em;
}
```

Que quedaría así:

```css
.a + .b {
  margin-top: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
   ...
   ...
   ...
</div>

<div class="b">
   ...
   ...
   ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya te han dado la respuesta en definitiva puedes usar margin, para separación entre etiquetas o padding para crear espacios dentro de las mismas. Voy a ampliar sus respuestas explicandote que lo mejor es usar la medida **"em"** para los saltos de línea, esto es, porque es una medida dinámica que corresponde al tamaño de fuente seleccionada, un ejemplo:

Si el body, elemento padre, ancestro, contenedor o mismo elemento tiene declarado un font-size de 10px, el padding-top de 4em del hijo o anidado tendría un valor en pixeles de 40px o 4 saltos de línea.

```
body { font-size: 10px; }
div, .hijo, .anidado{padding-top: 4em;} /*40px*/
```

Si el elemento padre tiene declarado un font-size de 12px, entonces esos 4em, equivaldrían a 12px X 4 = 48px. Si el mismo elemento le declaras otra medida de tamaño de fuente, esta sería la que se usa de referencia para calcular los saltos de linea entonces:

```
div, .hijo, .anidado{font-size: 20px; padding-top: 4em;} 
/*Esos 4em se convertirían en 80px*/
```

Y si por ejemplo tienes un elemento declarado con un tamaño de fuente X, pero en realidad quieres tomar como base el tamaño de letra declarado por default en el body, puedes usar la medida **"rem"**, ejemplo:

```
body { font-size: 10px; }

h1 { font-size: 24px; }

h1 span { 
  /*Lo siguiente se calcularia en base al tamaño declarado en el 
  padre, es decir, 24px*/
  padding-top: 2em; } /*Es decir: 2 saltos de linea = 48px*/
  /*Lo siguiente se calcularia en base al tamaño declarado en el body
  es decir, 10px*/
  margin-top: 2rem; /*Es decir: 20px*/
}
```

Es una forma de hacer dinámicamente saltos de línea teniendo en cuenta una sola medida y puedes aplicarla también a tamaños: width, height, border, etc, y otra ventaja es que no se deformará al hacer zoom con el teclado.

```css
body{font-size: 16px; font-family: arial;}

.fuente-big{ font-size: 30px;  }
.fuente-small{ font-size: 12px;  }

[class*="fuente"]{
  padding-top: 4em;
}

[class*="fuente"].fuente-base{
  padding-top: 4rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

/*Los otros son estilos decorativos*/

div{  
  background: cyan;
  width: 49%;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 200px;
}

div:nth-child(4), div:nth-child(3){ background: lightcyan; }
```

```html
<body>
  <h3>El body tiene declarado 16 px.</h3>
  <div class="fuente-big">
    <span> Letra 30px, padding-top: 4em </span>
  </div>
  <div class="fuente-small">
    <span> Letra 12px, padding-top: 4em </span>
  </div>
  <div class="fuente-big fuente-base">
    <span> Letra 30px, padding-top: 4rem </span>
  </div>
  <div class="fuente-small fuente-base">
    <span> Letra 12px, padding-top: 4rem </span>
  </div>https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128345/saltos-de-l%c3%adnea-entre-dos-divs#
```

Espero te haya quedado más claro y sino, dejame un comentario con cualquier otra duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Edgar, tus respuestas son muy ejemplares. Excelente trabajo.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de hacerlo es a través de márgenes. Puedes darle margen bottom al div a o margen top al div b de la siguiente forma:

Deberías calcular en píxeles cuantos son 4 
 y modificar 10 por esa cantidad.

```
.a {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

ó

```
.b {
  margin-top:10px;
}
```